# Closures in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Sample code:

```
def func(a, &closure)
  return a if a
  closure ||= lambda{ |words| puts "!!! " + words }
  closure.call("1")
  closure.call("2")
end

func(false){ |words| puts "??? " + words }
```

Please explain. I can not understand this line:

```
closure ||= lambda{ |words| puts "!!! " + words }
```

If you remove `||` will be permanently displayed as follows: `"!!! 1", "!!! 2"`. Why?
And also explain this:

```
def func(a, &closure)
```

where did `&closure`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def func(a, &closure)
    return a if a
    closure ||= lambda{ |words| puts "!!! " + words }
    closure.call("1")
    closure.call("2")
end

func(false){ |words| puts "??? " + words }
```

In "&closure" the ampersand (&) means that the function takes a block as a parameter.  What is happening is you are passing a Proc (a block is just a Proc defined with a different syntax) to the func function which is then called with the variable 1 and 2.

The ||= means "or equals."  It is used to assign a value to a variable if the current value is nil.  It is shorthand for:

```
closure = lamda{ |words| puts "!!! " + words } if closure.nil
```

[This blog post](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas) explains blocks, Procs and lamdas  well.

Answer (score 1):

The token `closure` here does not have any significance at all. It is just a local block variable given as an argument. When `func` is used with a block, `closure` will refer to that block. If not, it will initially be `nil`. What `||=` does is, when the variable is `nil`, it assigns what comes to the right. So if you use `func` with a block, `closure` will be that block; if you use it without a block, `closure` will be `lambda{...}`. Now, if you replace `||=` with `=`, then `closure` will always be `lambda{...}` irrespective of whether you use it with a block. `closure.call(1)` will substiture `1` to `words` in `closure`, and you will get the output `!!!1`; similarly with `closure.call(2)`, which outputs `!!!2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with the closures

```
closure ||= lambda{ |words| puts "!!! " + words }
```

||  says that, if the variable closure alreay initialized just use it, otherwise initialize the new lambda ambda{ |words| puts "!!! " + words }

since you are passing the lambda already

```
func(false){ |words| puts "??? " + words }
```

default lambda (having !!!) not initialized

But if you remove the ||, it always initialize the new lambda

You can print the !!! without removing ||, just call

```
   func(false)
```